# python multithread at output information

Tags: python, multithreading

Complete code (from below github linked page):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import threading
import time
import random
import copy

exitFlag = 0

class checkup (threading.Thread):  #繼承thred 檢查流程
  def __init__(self, threadID, patientList, patientStatus):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.patientList = patientList
    self.patientStatus = patientStatus
  def run(self):                   #檢查中
    while True:
      if(check(self.patientList)):
        break
      for i in range( 0, 2, 1):
        for status in self.patientStatus:
          if status['name'] == self.patientList[i]['name'] and status['status'] == False and self.patientList[i]['status'] == False:
            status['status'] = True
            checkTime = random.randint(1,3)
            print "%s: %s check time(%d)" % (self.patientList[i]['name'], self.threadID, checkTime)
            time.sleep(checkTime)
            self.patientList[i]['status'] = True
            status['status'] = False
            time.sleep(1)

#check all patients have to be ckecked
def check(patientList):
  checkFlag = False
  for patient in patientList:
    if patient['status'] == True:
      checkFlag = True
    else:
      checkFlag = False
  if checkFlag:
    return True
  else:
    return False

# patients init
patients = [{
  'name': 'Kevin',
  'status': False
},{
  'name': 'Tom',
  'status': False
}]

# Outpatient init
random.shuffle(patients)
Cardiology = {
  'name': 'Cardiology',
  'patientList':  copy.deepcopy(patients),
  'patientStatus': patients
}
CardiologyCheckup = checkup('Cardiology', Cardiology['patientList'], Cardiology['patientStatus'])

random.shuffle(patients)
Chest = {
  'name': 'Chest',
  'patientList':  copy.deepcopy(patients),
  'patientStatus': patients
}
ChestCheckup = checkup('Chest', Chest['patientList'], Chest['patientStatus'])

ChestCheckup.start()
CardiologyCheckup.start()
```

Source here: [https://github.com/stevekevin1005/OS/blob/master/os.py]

I want it's output:

```
Tom: Chest check time(1)
Kevin: Cardiology check time(2)
Kevin: Chest check time(1)
Tom: Cardiology check time(1)
```

but sometimes:

```
Kevin: Chest check time(2)
Tom: Cardiology check time(3)
Tom: Chest check time(1)
```

just three line

What's mistake I make?

---

How can I create a element like object?
ex.

```
a={
 'a': 1,
 'b': 2
}
#a[a] 1
#a[b] 2
```

Comment: Could you include the code into the question (or a snippet if it's too long) instead of a link? Also, it seems that your code is a bit messy. Have a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Thanks for editing. Is there a reason, why instead of pasting the 72 complete lines of code, you only insert some portion in the question?

Comment: I can't pastsing all code, it seems be too long to paste

Comment: I was able ;-) Edit should appear soon. I will provide some PEP8 conforming version derived from it and starting point to find the error / conceptual problem in your code maybe more easily and also hopefully helps you get started with enhancing your Python coding skills even more.

Comment: Please check my solution / answer. But what do you exactly want, where you write at the bottom of the question: "element like object". Please add detail - or maybe as comment to my answer, so I can add this to provide a complete solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So as promised here is a PEP8 ok version (note also changed names in variables and keys to the used dicts). It should - besides answering the question - help the OP to grok the transformations (as @MoonCheesez suggested in comment) made.

Note that I also already deleted the unsued exitFlag module level variable, streamlined some logical evaluations w.r.t. False, True and used **kwargs to make the parameter chaining more easy on the eyes.

Also note, that I interpreted the will comparing all these variables to False or True was not best represented as "is False" (eg) but really only the truthiness or falsiness.

So here comes a pepified version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
"""Explain here what this module has to offer."""
from __future__ import print_function
import copy
import random
import sys
import threading
import time


class CheckUp(threading.Thread):
    """Explain here what this class represents and some usage hints."""
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = kwargs['area_name']
        self.patient_list = kwargs['patient_list']
        self.patients_w_status = kwargs['patients_w_status']

    def run(self):
        """Describe logic of processing here."""
        s_k, n_k = 'status', 'name'
        busy_sleep_secs = 1
        while True:
            if check(self.patient_list):
                break
            for i in range(0, 2, 1):
                for status in self.patients_w_status:
                    if status[n_k] == self.patient_list[i][n_k]:
                        if not (status[s_k] or self.patient_list[i][s_k]):
                            status[s_k] = True
                            check_time = random.randint(1, 3)
                            print("%s: %s check time(%d)"
                                  "" % (self.patient_list[i][n_k],
                                        self.threadID, check_time))
                            time.sleep(check_time)
                            self.patient_list[i][s_k] = True
                            status[s_k] = False
                            time.sleep(busy_sleep_secs)


def check(patient_list):
    """Check all patients have to be checked."""
    check_flag = False
    for patient in patient_list:
        check_flag = True if patient['status'] else False
    return check_flag


def main():
    """Drive the endeavour."""
    # patients init
    patients = [{
        'name': 'Kevin',
        'status': False
    }, {
        'name': 'Tom',
        'status': False
    }]

    # Outpatient init
    random.shuffle(patients)
    cardiology = {
        'area_name': 'Cardiology',
        'patient_list': copy.deepcopy(patients),
        'patients_w_status': copy.deepcopy(patients)
    }
    cardiologyCheckup = CheckUp(**cardiology)

    random.shuffle(patients)
    chest = {
        'area_name': 'Chest',
        'patient_list': copy.deepcopy(patients),
        'patients_w_status': copy.deepcopy(patients)
    }
    chestCheckup = CheckUp(**chest)

    chestCheckup.start()
    cardiologyCheckup.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

When called without also using `copy.deepcopy(patients)` as value for the `patients_w_status` key in the dicts:

```
$> python2 so_threading_output.py
Kevin: Chest check time(1)
Tom: Cardiology check time(2)
Tom: Chest check time(2)

$> python2 so_threading_output.py
Kevin: Chest check time(3)
Tom: Cardiology check time(1)
Tom: Chest check time(3)
```

When using above corrected version that also deep copies the patients dict into the patients_w_status key fields one has:

```
$> python2 so_threading_output.py
Tom: Chest check time(3)
Tom: Cardiology check time(2)
Kevin: Cardiology check time(1)
Kevin: Chest check time(3)

$> python2 so_threading_output.py
Kevin: Chest check time(3)
Tom: Cardiology check time(3)
Kevin: Cardiology check time(2)
Tom: Chest check time(2)
```

Does this solve the problem. It looks like, as there seems to be no reason to deepcopy one dict and shallow copy the other when it is being processed somehow alike.

Comment: Was going to post that too but was too busy pepifying it.

Comment: Maybe upvote it then? Naming and handling things is an important balance IMO to maintain and this is part of our anwser to the OP. Good tools help refactoring to restore a more adequate balance that here Python offered together with PEP8 from the start ...

Comment: Great, mind to tell the world how it was solved, so others may profit from it, and maybe accept my answer ;-) ?